# vuejs watch словарь

Tags: vue.js

Можно ли при отслеживании изменений словаря получить ключ значения, которое изменилось? К примеру у меня есть словарь reg_data{phone:",email:"} я отслеживаю его изменения при помощи watch, но как мне понять изменился phone или email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так ([codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/jp16230yl5)) -

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="user.email" />
    <input type="text" v-model="user.phone" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    user: {
      email: "",
      phone: ""
    }
  }),
  watch: {
    ["user.email"]: (oldValue, newValue) => console.log(oldValue, newValue),
    ["user.phone"]: (oldValue, newValue) => console.log(oldValue, newValue)
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, у меня немного задача изменилась. Теперь у меня массив словарей и при изменении любого поля мне нужно получить индекс этого поля или значение ключа id из словаря, не подскажете как это реализовать и возможно ли вообще?